# cannot apply multiple middlewares using Redux applyMiddleware function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Can anyone help me out with the right `redux store` configuration?

I am trying to configure as follows,

**configureStore.js**

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

let middlewares = [thunk, logger]

const configureStore = () => {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares)  // I also tried with applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
  );

  return store;
}

export default configureStore;
```

And I import this module main js file and use as follows,

**index.js**

```
import configureStore from '../stores/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

// And other DOM render code follows...
```

But is seems not working and the following error displays in the web console,

Error: Uncaught TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__compose**.a.apply(...) is not a function

[image: Error]

File in which the error is:
[image]

I am following official docs of `redux`, `redux-thunk` and `redux-logger` but unable to make it work.

Another note: It works fine when I remove any one of `thunk` and `logger` from the middlewares list.

> **UPDATE:**  I got temporary fix

Downgrading `redux` from `3.7.2` to `3.5.2` works fine.

I still wonder why it is the problem with latest version of `Redux`. I tried to add more information related to the issue and looking for solution for future upgrades.

Thanks!

Comment: I notice that `rootReducer` is used in configureStore.js, but is never defined or imported. Is that the problem? Or did you just leave it out from the example?

Comment: rootReducer is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You just made a tiny mistake.

From the official [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html), here is the signature of createStore:

```
createStore(reducer, [preloadedState], [enhancer])
```

You mixed up the order of the arguments, passing your enhancer function (applyMiddleware) where the function is expecting the preloadedState. You need to pass in an argument in between the rootReducer, and the applyMiddleware function, in order to satisfy the signature.

Hope this helped!

Comment: `createStore` _does_ actually support passing the enhancer as the second argument, instead of `preloadedState`.

Comment: No luck. I tried passing default state object as second argument. I think @markerikson is right